# console.log is not showing correct values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to console an object although it's not throwing any error but the result i want is shown after some time and I am not able to retrieve it.

It shows an i icon which says 'value below was evaluated just now' and I am not able to get that values .

```
OUTPUT: Promise {$$state: {…}}
        $$state:
        status:1
        value:"Modifier"
        __proto__:Object
        __proto__:Object
```

And I need that value:"MODIFIER" in a variable. How to get it. Thanks in advance.

console.log($translate('MODIFY'));
I am using angular-translate inside a controller.

When I use console.log($translate('MODIFY')['$$state'].value) it shows undefined just because of the reason "value below was evaluated just now". I need the later values or any way to get them before.

Comment: show us what you have done so far...

Comment: please add some code, that seems to be a `promise object` rather than an `object`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: seems you need to know how to get a value from an asynchronous call - which is easy with a Promise - but as you've shown **absolutely zero code** then there's not much more can be said

Comment: Thanks all, I really don't know much about promises and this helps me  lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a promise, which will return you values asynchronously(i.e out of the flow of execution). The correct way to handle this is as follows:

`promiseObj.then(function(value){//you're code here})`

When i was staring out this here helped me understand promises.

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks this helps me